# Wrong output when dealing with multiple python files for one project

Tags: python, oop, modular-design

Sorry if I asked a silly question or made an obvious mistake as OOPS is not my strong point!

I have a project for which I am using Python. I have written all the code in a single function and it works as expected, giving proper output dataframe.

But when I try to **break that one function into multiple functions all present in different .py files, all the files present in one local directory**, the output then gets changed. The output dataframe then contains all **nan values**.

```
main.py (only one file which contains all the code)

    def fn():
        .
        .
        .
        return x
```

Here x is the expected result and it works. But if I do this:

```
sub_module1.py (file #1)

class a:
    def __init__(self):
        pass:
    
    def fn1(self, para1):
        .
        .
        return x


sub_module2.py (file #2)

class b:
    def__init__(self):
        pass:

    def fn2(self, para2):
        .
        .
        return y


main.py (file #3)

from sub_module1 import a
from sub_module2 import b

x1 = a().fn1(para1)
x2 = b().fn2(para2)

def fn3(some parameters):
    # some logic which makes use of x1 and x2
    return new_x
```

**new_x has nan values** which don't make sense to me as the **code is the same as used in main.py**. The only difference is that instead of using **one single function for the whole code**, I have broken down the code into **multiple functions which are stored in different python files but in the same directory and then I am calling those functions into one single python file(main.py)** to get the output.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In `fn1()` and `fn2()` you are returning `a` and `b` respectively. Are these supposed to be class instance objects of `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Lihka_nonem I am new to OOPS so I dont know what instance objects are. Also I have edited the question to change the variables names being returned from `fn1()` and `fn2()` from `a` and `b` to `x` and `y` so that there is no confusion between class name and the variable being returned by the function. Basically `fn1()` and `fn2()` are returning 2 variables `x` and `y` respectively which are then being used by importing their respective classes in the `main.py` file.

Comment: The  code you have there will not work.  You would need `def __init__(self):` and `def fn1(self, para1):` and `def fn2(self, para2)`.  Is that actually what you have?  I think your "retyping" has introduced enough mistakes that we can't analyze it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you. Typo on my part! Yes I have edited the question. There are 3 `.py` files, first one has `class a:` which has a function `fn1(self, para1)` which returns a. Similarly file 2 has `class b:` which consists of a function `fn2(self, para2)` which returns `b`. Third file has a function which calls both the functions.

Comment: @spectre, Please refer these - [link1](https://towardsdatascience.com/practical-python-class-vs-instance-variables-431fd16430d), [link2](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module4_OOP/ClassInstances.html)

Comment: There's simply not enough information here.  Remember, as one example, that globals do not cross file boundaries.  If you have a global `data` in `main.py` and a `data` in `sub_module1.py`, they are unrelated.  Updates to one will not be seen in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, there is an issue with the logic inside `fn3()` or the way you are calling `fn3()`.

If you are calling `fn3()` as shown below -

```
# main.py (file #3)

from sub_module1 import a
from sub_module2 import b

x1 = a().fn1(para1)
x2 = b().fn2(para2)

def fn3(some parameters):
    # some logic which makes use of x1 and x2
    return new_x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_x = fn3(some parameters)
```

Then what will happen is that `x1` and `x2` values will not have the values returned by your methods as their initialization is done outside the scope of `f3()`. Also, I hope `some parameters` include `x1` and `x2`. If it doesn't, it's better to make sure that you are doing that explicitly. I would rewrite your code to  do the following -

```
# main.py (file #3)

from sub_module1 import a
from sub_module2 import b

def fn3(some parameters, x1, x2):
    # some logic which makes use of x1 and x2
    return new_x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x1 = a().fn1(para1)
    # print(x1) for sanity checking.
    x2 = b().fn2(para2)
    # print(x2) for sanity checking.
    new_x = fn3(some parameters, x1, x2)
```

The alternate approach is to get the values of `x1` and `x2` inside `fn3()`. Then your code would look as follows -

```
# main.py (file #3)

from sub_module1 import a
from sub_module2 import b

def fn3(some parameters):
    x1 = a().fn1(para1)
    # print(x1) for sanity checking.
    x2 = b().fn2(para2)
    # print(x2) for sanity checking.
    # some logic which makes use of x1 and x2
    return new_x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_x = fn3(some parameters)
```

If this still returns `new_x` as a `NAN` value, I would debug line by line what's happening inside `fn3()` as the issue surely lies over there.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information in his question to formulate anything approaching an answer.  You're making a series of assumptions about what he wants that are not supported by the code.

Comment: @Lihka_nonem Thank you for your input. My implementation was correct but as you suggested to check the implementation of `fn3()`, it was indeed the culprit. Also the code implementation and the links you gave were helpful. +1 for the effort bud!

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry about that. The reason I could not post more details about the code was because it was confidential. But other than that I will try to be more descriptive next time for sure!